# Calling a function with vector<class>

Tags: c++, class, vector

```
int existsInVector(vector<string> &data, string str)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++)
    {
        if (data[i] == str)
        {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

I defined this function in order to check if 'data' vector includes 'str' string. But I have a problem which I didn't understand even a little while calling it:

```
istringstream linestream(line);
            linestream >> id >> grade;
            student.setId(id);
            string new_id = student.getId();
            studvec.push_back(Student());
            student.setPoints(grade);
            total_grade = student.getGrade("hw", grade) + student.getGrade("mt", grade) + student.getGrade("f", grade);
            int idx = existsInVector(studvec, new_id);
```

I know there are lots of mistakes in this code, but I didn't understand the problem, can someone explain me the mistake and its solution?

Comment: What is the problem you have?

Comment: @NathanPierson compiler gives me an error in line: int idx = existsInVector(studvec, new_id);  (no matching function for call to 'existsInVector') , I think I am calling it wrong.

Comment: `studvec.push_back(Student());` take a look at what you're putting in the vector. What relation does it have to the `student` object you're modifying?

Comment: @Kevin I am still on my learning process and unfortunately I don't know how can I push back a string inside a vector<class>, I did it like

student.setId(id);
string new_id = student.getId();
studvec.push_back(new_id);

But it gives an error =(

Comment: If you are still on your learning process, use `bool` data type for `true/fase` values, not integers.  Wow, numbers for Boolean is over 50 years old.  Time to use newer data types.

Answer (score 3):

You said you want to pass a `vector` of `string`s to the `existsInVector` method, however what you are actually passing is a `vector` of `Student`.

You can instead change the method to accept a `vector` of `Student`s, and then access the `id` property of the `Student` class/struct inside the loop.